# How to turn `Either[Error, Option[Either[Error, Account]]]` to `Either[Error, Option[Account]]` with typelevel cats?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, either, scala-option

I'm using [cats](http://typelevel.org/cats), wonder how to turn a data with it.

From

```
val data = Either[Error, Option[Either[Error, Account]]]
```

to

```
val target: Either[Error, Option[Account]] = howToConvert(data)
```

If there is any `Error` happens, the result will be `Left(error)` with the first appeared error.

I can do it now with:

```
data match {
  case Left(e) => Left(e)
  case Right(Some(Right(y))) => Right(Some(y))
  case Right(Some(Left(e))) => Left(e)
  case Right(None) => Right(None)
}
```

But I'm looking for some easy way

Comment: Should `Right(None)` be mapped to `Right(None)`?

Comment: @thesamet Yes, thanks! I will update it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to `sequence` the inner `Option`, so that you get an `Either[Error, Either[Error, Option[Account]]]` and then flatten it.
With cats syntax this is really easy:

```
import cats.implicits._

val target: Either[Error, Option[Account]] =
  data.flatMap(_.sequence)
```

To clarify, `sequence` turns a type constructor "inside out", meaning the inner `Option[Either[Error, Account]]` is turned into an `Either[Error, Option[Account]]`.

Comment: Nice, but what else needs to get imported? I am getting: ```polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : [G[_], A]G[Option[A]]
[error]  required: scala.util.Either[Error,Option[Account]]
[error]   val my: Either[Error, Option[Account]] = data.flatMap(_.sequence)```

Comment: Those are all the imports you need. You might need to enable `-Ypartial-unification` though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an "easy" way that only assumes a right-biased Either (Scala 2.12), or cats' syntax

```
val target: Either[Error, Option[Account]] =
    data.flatMap(_.map(_.map(Some(_))).getOrElse(Right(None)))
```